# deploying flask-restful app using apache mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, flask-restful

I'm trying to create a flask-restful based app, but not able to host it properly. Here is my virtual host file `FlaskApp.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName flaskapp

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/flaskapp/myopinion.wsgi

<Directory /var/www/flaskapp/flaskapp>
    WSGIProcessGroup myopinion
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and my wsgi file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/flaskapp/")
from server import app as application
```

---

Server is my python module stored in `/var/www/flaskapp/flaskapp` directory.

My virtual host file is located at `/etc/apache2/sites_available/`
and my .wsgi file is located in `/var/www/flaskapp` directory.

When I'm trying to access my urls from `server.py` file it is giving error code `404 Not found: requested url /ques/ was not found on this server`.

I'm in desperate need of help here, I'm stuck with this problem since past two weeks. Please help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a problem with your virtual host file. Try this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName flaskapp

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/flaskapp/myopinion.wsgi
WSGIProcessGroup myopinion

<Directory /var/www/flaskapp/flaskapp/>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Your wsgi file is also not correct. It should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/flaskapp/")

from flaskapp import server as application
```

In the wsgi file, you put the directory name after `from`, the object name after `import`. Aliasing it as `application` is not necessary, but a common practice.

Comment: Can you post the script that contains your route definitions? This would be the place that creates the `/ques` route and maps it to a class.

Comment: Your link is broken; it has a ] at the end. It is better to post the relevant code as an edit to your original question, in case others have a similar question in the future. What URL are you trying to hit? http://localhost/ques or http://localhost/ques/1 or which endpoint are you trying to hit?

Comment: https://github.com/manish0992/project/blob/master/server.py  follow this link for script... i'm trying to hit localhost/ques/1

Answer (score 0):

I used a similar apache-flask redirection for my flask application. You can take a look at the tutorial which i followed.

Link : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps

The mod_wsgi setup worked for me using the above link. I used it to redirect Flask port:5000 to Port 80 on apache2. It is possible to install and enable mod_wsgi using the following commands in a shell:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi python-dev
sudo a2enmod wsgi
```

Once the installation is done and everything is configured correctly, Apache has to be restarted using the following command:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: It is better to explain your solution, than just posting code or links. If you post a link it's fine, but you better put here a summary with the most important steps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16991653)

Comment: Thanks for the advice . I'll keep that in mind . New to stackoverflow.